# Grafana : How to create new dashboard and datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am pretty new to grafana. I am trying to follow the tutorial on the website but my screen does not look anything like the ones mentioned in the tutorials. I have

[image]

so it is completely balnk! there is no option where i can navigate for creating a new dashboard or adding a data source. i want to link grafana to my elasticsearch indices. How do i do that? Am i missing some configuration?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new data source you need to be either [organization admin or grafana admin](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/admin/). 
When you have required rights there will be [`Datasources` button](http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/) under `Dashboards` button.
To create new dashboard toggle dashboard dropdown under `Home` label.`New` button is on the lower left corner.

[image: Create new dashboard]

Comment: how do i become organization admin or grafana admin?

Comment: If Grafana setting `users.allow_org_create` is set to `true` you can create your own organization and automatically become administrator of it. It is `false` by default. If it set to `false` you need to contact person who is responsible for administration of your Grafana instance, and ask them to either adjust setting or give you required permission. As my understanding goes there is no built-in way to do so.